# I don't know why while sending the variable to HTML it is showing UnboundLocalError. I tried similar Stackoverflow solution but it didn't solve

Tags: python, flask

[image: Error]

I don't know why while sending the variable to HTML it is showing *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prdct' referenced before assignment*.

When I don't pass any values from **render_template()** method then the code is running fine. Also the output that I'm printing using *print(prdct)* is also working fine.

**Following is my code:**

[image: Code part-1: python file]

[image: Code part-2: HTML]

Comment: On PUT,GET,... Any other  then POST you never declare the `prdct` variable  - that is why. Any time the `if ...:` is not entered, variables that are in it do not get created . You cannot use those to return them. move that before the if or indent the return inside the if and return smth differenc in case of GET,PUT,...

Comment: @PatrickArtner Can you please help me with the code if you don't mind. Where I should make the changes? I'm new to this thing :)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not create `prdct` in all cases when executing the function. Only when you are entering this with `request.Method = "POST"` it will work.

You cannot return something unconditionally that may not have been created:

```
def test():
    if False:
        k = 42

    return k


test()
```

will throw the a different error your code - the reasons are similar.

The `if` condition is not met, `k = 42` is never created - so you cannot return it in all possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that if predict.py, whatever function is in there, gets called with an http request other than POST, the `prdct` variable is undefined.

You have two options:

1. Define `prdct = None` at a higher scope than your POST method condition
2. Move that specific return statement inside your POST method condition block

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. It's working now:)